# If given $\gamma$ find the integral

Tags: complex-analysis

Hi i would like some help with the following integral! Just tell me what to do and i will do it myself:

The exercise goes like this:

If$\gamma=-i+5e^{2it}$ for $t\in [0;2\pi]$ the $\int_\gamma \frac {dz}z=?$

The answers says its $4\pi i$

I was thinking since is of the type $\int f(z)dz$ with $f(z)= \frac 1{z-z_0}$ with $z_0=0$ i was thinking of going for $\int$=2$\pi f(z_0)$ but $\frac 10$ doesnt make any sense here . Can you help me?

Comment: Hint: Cauchy Formula. Draw the circle and note where the pole is.

Comment: @SeanRoberson The formula is $f(z_0)=\frac 1 {2\pi i} \int _\gamma \frac {f(z)}{z-z_0} $right?

Comment: @SeanRoberson with $z_0 =0$ and $f(z)=1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this is only a hint and doesn't give it all away ...

Break up the parametrization of $\gamma$ into two parts:

$$t\in [0,\pi], \quad \text{and} \quad t\in (\pi,2\pi]$$

How many times do you traverse a circle?